# How can i add another button intent beside previous one?

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-intent

Here is my code:
 it contains a button named as **button1A** and when I click on it, It  opens a list named as **list1**.
How can I put a code for my another button named as button2A which open a list as List2.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

public class Tab_1st extends Activity {

Button button1A;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tablayout1);

    addListenerOnButton();


}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button1A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1A);

    button1A.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent a1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), List1.class);
            startActivity(a1);

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: why you want to create 2 buttons??? Instead you can create a Tab Layout where you can switch between 2 list items in a single activity.Try Tab Layout.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `addListenerOnButton` method using `switch-case` to minimize code and add single `OnClickListener` listener to multiple button as :

```
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button1A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1A);
        button1A.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);
        // add OnClickListener to second Button 
        button1B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1B);
        button1B.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);
    OnClickListener clicklistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.button1A: 
                    // start second List Activity
               Intent a1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), List1.class);
               startActivity(a1);
               break;

          case R.id.button2A: 
                     // start second List Activity
               Intent a2 = new Intent(v.getContext(), List2.class);
               startActivity(a2);
               break;

        }
       }
     };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add more click listeners if you want. try like this.

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

button1A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1A);

button1A.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent a1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), List1.class);
        startActivity(a1);

    }
});

button2A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2A);

button2A.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), List2.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this can be by implementing the OnClickListener.

```
public class Tab_1st extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button button1A;
Button button2A;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tablayout1);
    button1A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1A);
    button2A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2A);
    button1A.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2A.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == button1A) {
        // Start Activity a1
        Intent a1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), List1.class);
        startActivity(a1);
    } else if (v == button2A) {
        // Start Activity a2
        Intent a2 = new Intent(v.getContext(), List2.class);
        startActivity(a2);
    }

}

}
```