# 8 button intent crash

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-intent

okay thanks for read.
i have a 8 button for 8 intent.

in button 1 intent. works corectly. and open another class.
but when i try to click button 2 - 8 and then crash.

i have add 8 class to manifest but still  crash.

my question is. how to implements more than 1 intent button ?

this my main code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button1;
Button button02;
Button button3;
Button button4;
Button button5;
Button button6;
Button button7;
Button button8;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);

    // Capture button clicks
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Bbarung.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    button02.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg1) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Bpanerus.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);


        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg2) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Gong.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg3) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Kenong.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg4) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Sbarung.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    button6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg5) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Sdemung.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    button7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg6) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Spanerus.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    button8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg7) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Slenthem.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

and this my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="1280px"
       android:layout_height="309px"
       android:background="@drawable/buttonbbarung" />

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button02"
       android:layout_width="1280px"
       android:layout_height="309px"
       android:background="@drawable/buttonbpanerus" />

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button3"
       android:layout_width="1280px"
       android:layout_height="309px"
       android:background="@drawable/buttongong" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
       android:layout_width="1280px"
       android:layout_height="309px"
       android:background="@drawable/buttonkenong" />

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button5"
       android:layout_width="1280px"
       android:layout_height="309px"
       android:background="@drawable/buttonsbarung" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
       android:layout_width="1280px"
       android:layout_height="309px"
       android:background="@drawable/buttonsdemung" />



    <Button
         android:id="@+id/button7"
       android:layout_width="1280px"
       android:layout_height="309px"
       android:background="@drawable/buttonspanerus" />



    <Button
         android:id="@+id/button8"
       android:layout_width="1280px"
       android:layout_height="309px"
       android:background="@drawable/buttonslenthem" />


</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

my manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.main.Bbarung"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.main.Bpanerus"
        android:label="@string/hello_world"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.main.Gong"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.main.Kenong"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.main.Sbarung"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.main.Sdemung"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.main.Spanerus"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.main.Slenthem"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

last is my logcat error

```
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): java.lang.RuntimeException:       
Unable to start activity   
ComponentInfo{com.example.main/com.example.main.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.main.MainActivity cannot be cast   
to android.view.View$OnClickListener
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at  
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at   
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at 

   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.main.MainActivity cannot be cast 
to android.view.View$OnClickListener
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at    
com.example.main.MainActivity.addListenerOnButton(MainActivity.java:36)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at 
com.example.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at     
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at     
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-08 19:34:45.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     ... 11 more
```

thanks for your advice
this make me so frustated
i try other method, but still make me confused for 8 button intent

method
[How can i add another button intent beside previous one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534912/how-can-i-add-another-button-intent-beside-previous-one#_=_)

**- Problem Solved -**

my mistakes is am not adding  "addListenerOnButton" into my program.

but this links can resolved for multiple activities

[How to have multiple buttons in one activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755487/how-to-have-multiple-buttons-in-one-activity)

just add in .xml code

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

and use this in .java

```
public void onClick(View v){
```

it's works for me. thanks for helping. :)

Comment: Where is the addListenerOnButton method in your code above? It says the crash occurs there but I do not see any such method in the code you posted above.

Comment: thankss!!!! thats my big problem. im not to add" addListenerOnButton" . and i found the another method, not need addListenerOnButton anymore.. thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

clean project and try again.
[how to clean android project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ihk.png)